# CSS only drop down broken on recent Chrome only with hover border-radius

Tags: google-chrome

The question is: is this a new Chrome bug or is something about my css causing the problem. I have created a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/tomba/ayoeebbs/1/ which reproduces the issue rather than include all the drop-down's css here.

The drop down menu worked fine on all current versions of IE, Firefox, Safari and Chrome until recently. Starting with either Chrome 42 or 43 this drop down is broken. When you hover over the anchor div the drop down shows but as soon as you move into it it vanishes - meaning no items can be selected. I have narrowed it to the border-radius line in this css:

```
#drop-menu:hover {
  background: #888;
  border-top: 1px solid #666;
  border-right: 1px solid #666;
  border-left: 1px solid #666;
  border-radius: 5px;   /* remove this and Chrome is happy again */
}
```

If the border-radius:5px; is commented out all is good again. This seems very strange and is pretty new in that I haven't changed my code in months. I have seen a few somewhat related questions but none (I've seen) that find the problem to be something so innocuous seeming.

It is not a big deal to me to remove the border-radius though I'd prefer to keep it but obviously won't for now at least as it completely breaks navigation. Mostly I want to know if I'm causing the problem somehow and only Chrome is "doing the right thing."

Comment: The `border-radius` bit is interesting, but the actual problem is that the `#dropmenu` has a 25px `height` and `max-height` so that it is no longer hovered and the sub menu collapses. Remove that height, [like this example](http://jsfiddle.net/bgkexfL0/), and it works fine. `border-radius` doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you @misterManSam! I think those height lines are something from early dev of the site this is on and should have gone long ago - don't remember why I ever had them and I was blinded by the first removed thing that made the problem go away. So this seems to fall into Chrome is lately doing the right thing and all others are not: really I should have had a problem on all browsers. Very glad I have an explanation that makes way more sense - though, yes, the fact that removing the radius line made Chrome "revert" is interesting but not terribly now. Thanks again for your eagle eye.